# Почему ответы новичков никто не оценивает?

Tags: обсуждение, репутация, новички

Часто замечаю, что ответы людей с низкой репутацией не оцениваются. Никто не нажимает на кнопку "ответ полезен", никто не комментирует. 
Не дай бог, новичок ошибся - куча минусов, агрессивные комментарии. Что происходит?

Comment: "Здесь так принято" (ц)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ "Здесь так не принято" (ц)

Comment: Судя по вашему профилю, вы набрали 20 бубл. и можете плюсовать за сообщения с 8-го апр. сего года, однако вы отдали пока 11 голосов, не так уж и много.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

К сожалению в вопросе нет примеров (и у вашего профиля тоже нету ответов), чтобы можно было на чем-то базироваться, поэтому отвечу в общем:

Могу предположить, что ответы не оцениваются ввиду их посредственного качества, независимо от авторства. В то же время, наличие репутации кореллирует с наличием качественных ответов в прошлом, т.е. с умением их писать в целом. Также, опытный участник скорее не станет давать средний ответ, а напишет его в комментариях.

Итого: посредственные ответы (которые чаще даются новичками) заслуженно игнорируются, а хорошие ответы (которые даются более опытными участниками) заслуженно плюсуются.

Comment: Наверное, я ошибся